# Enemy beelines before wandering in 2d topdown

Tags: unity, c#, ai

I'm making a top down shooter in Unity. The enemy AI travels straight to the middle of the screen before actually starting wandering when I put in this code. What can I do to fix this? (I'm using Unity 2019.4.28f1 if that helps).
I copied the code in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdNervYWmcE).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyWander : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float speed;
    [SerializeField]
    float range;
    [SerializeField]
    float maxDis;
    Vector2 Waypoint;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        setNewDes();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, Waypoint, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position,Waypoint) < range)
        {
            setNewDes();
        }
    }
    void setNewDes()
    {
        Waypoint = new Vector2(Random.Range(-maxDis, maxDis), Random.Range(-maxDis, maxDis));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed weird. `Start` should be called before the first `Update` and initialize `Waypoint` with a random value. Perhaps you forgot to set a value for `maxDis` in the inspector? But if it were 0, then the object would get stuck at the `0:0` point and not wander after reaching it. If I were you I would set a couple debugger breakpoints to find out what's actually happening to the variable `Waypoint` and when.

Comment: I did set the value for **maxDis** in the inspector but the enemy keep moving straight to 0:0 and after that it begin to wander randomly like it should be

Comment: So? What happens when you set a debugger breakpoint in `Start` and `Update` and watch the value of `Waypoint`?

Comment: Ok so I place the breakpoint at the `waypoint` and visual studio show the value is `(0.0,0.0)` but its should be random in the set range. I also set the `maxDis` to 3

Comment: I tried the code you posted in a new project and it works as it should - the gameObject moves to a different point everytime I enter test mode. So the problem has to be somewhere outside of that script.

Comment: Check to see if you have more than one instance of this script in your scene. The one you're looking at, that has maxDis set correctly, might not be the one that's misbehaving during gameplay.

Answer (score 1):

With the code in `setNewDes()` you are moving the enemies towards a position that is always relative to the position of the parent `x: 0, y: 0`, which in your case appears to be the scene itself.

By adding the new position to the current position, the new calculation destination would be relative to the current position:

```
void setNewDes() {
    Waypoint = new Vector2(
        transform.position.x + Random.Range(-maxDistance, maxDistance),
        transform.position.y + Random.Range(-maxDistance, maxDistance)
    );
}
```